# Stacked Inline with many rows crashing in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

When trying to navigate to 'Add a presentation' in Django admin, I have to wait ~1 minute for the response to render.  The problem is that I have ~500 slides in the database and the admin is selecting all the slides three different times to fill in the  menues. I am obviously doing something wrong with my model definitions, as I wouldn't expect this amount of data to bring my server to its knees.  Any visibility into why I am experiencing this issue with the way I have defined relationships or am using the django admin?

```
class PresentationTitle(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    order_number = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class PresentationUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    authorized_modules = models.ManyToManyField(PresentationTitle)


class Presentation(models.Model):
    title = models.ForeignKey(PresentationTitle)
    user = models.ForeignKey(PresentationUser)
    presentation_date = models.DateTimeField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title.title

class Slide(models.Model):
    ....

    submodule = models.ForeignKey(Submodule)

    presentation = models.ManyToManyField(Presentation, through='PresentationSlide')

    ...

    class Meta:
        order_with_respect_to = 'submodule'
        ordering = ['order']


class PresentationSlide(models.Model):
    presentation = models.ForeignKey(Presentation)
    slide = models.ForeignKey(Slide)
    slide_order = models.IntegerField()
```

Additionally, my admin contains:

```
class PresentationSlideInline(admin.StackedInline):                                                                                                                                                       
    model = PresentationSlide 

class PresentationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):                                                                                                                                                                
    inlines = [PresentationSlideInline]   

admin.site.register(Presentation, PresentationAdmin)
```

Understandably, removing just having PresentationAdmin from the `admin.site.register` makes it load very responsively.

Comment: Do you have any views associated with these models, or are you just using the built-in admin module?

Comment: These are just the built-in admin module.  Nothing custom on the view - just declaring a StackedInline for the Presentation on the admin.

Comment: What is this: return self.title.title? I think it's a mistake.

Comment: Do you need PresentationUser at all?  Why not just have a many to many foreign key in Presentation to User?

Comment: @sergzach `self.title.title` refers to the `title` field in `Module`

@PhoebeB `PresentationUser` has authorized_modules that User doesn't have.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved my issue -- there was another culprit at play:  *django-debug-toolbar*

After removing this from my setup, the admin panel for the Presentation effectively loads.

Thanks to everyone on the interest and the support, be wary of profiling add-ons when you are experience performance issues.